# Location tracking disabled, please go to Settings to adjust it. Error. iOS.Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, location

I'm using Xcode to create application. Where can I enable tracking location in Xcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to "go to Settings to adjust it?"

Comment: I couldn't find it in settings

Answer (score 0):

By importing the `CoreLocation` framework. Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/)

Comment: I imported CoreLocation. But I want to test it with Xcode on my computer, It works fine on iOS phone.

Comment: There's no way for the app to determine your location using the simulator. However, when you run the app on the simulator, go to the menu > debug > location and you can choose from a variety of preset options like Apple Headquarters, a bike/car ride or going on a walk to test your app's functionality